# Create an exponential equation with the following properties:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This isn't for a math class or anything, I'm just working on a game and need to find an equation with the following properties to balance part of it:

$x = 100, y = 1000$

$x = 50, y = 50$

$x = 0, y = 0$

I know I can just do something like

$0 \le x \le 50 | y = x$

$50 < x \le 100 | y = (0.095x^2) + 50$

But I want it to be continuous, like $y = cx^n$

Can anyone find this equation or tell me how one would go about doing it?

Comment: It looks like you start with $y = x$,  $x\leq 50$. Why not try, for $50\lt x\leq 100$, $y=10x$?  Of course, this would yield a discontinuous function, and depends on only 3 ordered pairs.  So I suggest you include other ordered pairs withing $0\leq x \leq 50$ (unless you intend that portion to be a straight line from the origin, with slope one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you could add more details, and explain what kind of other properties you expect from your function. As I understand, your function is not exactly exponential. Maybe some function like $y(x) = {x} (10^{\frac{x}{50} - 1})$ would serve your needs, maybe not.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I figured out how to tweak it too so I can use this for future things.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at $y:x \mapsto x\left(\dfrac{100-x}{50}+\dfrac{x-50}{5}\right)$, which is smooth and takes the values you want

Comment: So, $$x = 1 \mapsto x\left(\frac {99}{50} + \frac{10(-49)}{50}\right) = 1\;?$$  You've got some tweaking to do, unless you meant for the denominator of the second fraction in parentheses to be $50$. You currently are using $5$.

Comment: @amWhy OP does not want the value 1 at $x=1$. I have $y(0)=0$, $y(50)=50$ and $y(100)=1000$, as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You have three points, (100,1000), (50,50) and (0,0).  Because of the way you defined the function, y equals c times x to the n, we see that (0,0) is true for all values of c and n.  We now have two points and two degrees of freedom (c and n).  Therefore, there should be one equation that satisfies both.

We know that 1000 = c * (100) ^ n = c * 50^n * 2^n.  We also know that 50=c*50^n

Combine the two and you get 20 = 2^n, or n = log (base 2) 20.

Given n, it's trivial to find c, since c = 50 / (50^n) = 50^(1-n) = 50^(1 - log(base 2) 20).

Or, n ~= 4.32, c~= 2.27e-6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Graph of function]The best curve fit of the form

$$ y=e^{ax^2+bx+c}-1 $$

is when $a=-0.0019090979,\quad b=0.08819,\quad c=0$

These coefficients were found by doing a least-squares quadratic fit to the values of $\ln(y+1)$ using a TI-84 calculator.